# How can i solve this search button problem?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm newbie to Access VBA. I have a problem to execute this function for button SEARCH. When I execute the code, this error will appear on my screen:

[image: popup]

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()   
On Error GoTo cmdSearchErrorTrap
Dim MySQL As String, MyCriteria As String, MyRecordSource As String
Dim ArgCount As Integer
Dim Tmp As Variant
ArgCount = 0
MySQL = "Select * from [Incoming] where "
MyCriteria = ""
AddToWhere [Title], "[Title]", MyCriteria, ArgCount
AddToWhere [RefenrenceNum], "[RefenrenceNum]", MyCriteria, ArgCount
AddToWhere [LetterNumber], "[LetterNumber]", MyCriteria, ArgCount

If MyCriteria = "" Then
MyCriteria = "True"
End If
MyRecordSource = MySQL & MyCriteria
Me!frmEmpInf.Form.RecordSource = MyRecordSource
If Me!frmEmpInf.Form.RecordsetClone.RecordCount = 0 Then
MsgBox "No records match the criteria you entered.", 48, "No Records Found"
Me!cmdClear.SetFocus
Else
'Tmp = EnableControls("Detail", True)
Me!frmEmpInf.SetFocus
End If
btnSearchResume:
Exit Sub
btnSearchErrorTrap:
MsgBox Error$
Resume btnSearchResume
End Sub
```

Comment: Please tell us which part of your code is highlighted when you get that error message.

Comment: What is AddToWhere ? It looks like it's possibly a function? Where did you get this code from? Add Option Explicit to the top of all your code modules and try compiling it.

Answer (score -1):

Can you see what line is causing the error?  Just looking at your code I see your `On Error GoTo cmdSearchErrorTrap`statement but the corresponding statement at the bottom is `btnSearchErrorTrap`.  Fixing that so they are both prefixed with cmd or btn might be all you need (doesn't matter which as long as they're the same).